Scope of struct definition defined in a closure
I expected the following code to not compile, but it did compile (playground):
fn main() {
    (0..3)
        .map(|i| {
            struct S {
                v: usize,
            }
            S { v: i }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}

I thought every closure call would define a new struct type (and its instance) so the result couldn't be collected as a vector of some single type, but it seems S is not that local.
How does this work exactly under the hood? I want strict explanation such as a link to a page of The Rust Reference, so added #language-lawyer tag.

If you literally read the code above without knowing how Rust works, I think there can be two interpretations as shown below. I thought the second interpretation was correct, but the fact the code compiles implies the first one is correct. But why? That's my question.
Interpretation 1
//`S` is *global* in some sense.
struct S {
    v: usize,
}

//Every invocation of the closure just creates a new instance of the type `S`.
for i in 0..3 {
    vec.push(S { v: 0 });
}

Interpretation 2
{
    //Every invocation of the closure declares a new struct type
    // which is local to the invocation.
    struct __S_anonymous_01 {
        v: usize,
    }
    //And it then creates a new instance of that type.
    vec.push(__S_anonymous_01 { v: 0 });
}
{
    struct __S_anonymous_02 {
        v: usize,
    }
    vec.push(__S_anonymous_02 { v: 1 });
}
{
    struct __S_anonymous_03 {
        v: usize,
    }
    vec.push(__S_anonymous_03 { v: 2 });
}

//And `__S_anonymous_{01|02|03}` are all different
// though they have the same structure
// because Rust doesn't support duck typing.


It's a new struct, but not a new struct TYPE in each loop.  Right?  There's only one type S here.

@TimRoberts If you literally read the code without knowing how Rust works, I think there can be two interpretations: (1) struct S { ... } is defined (or should I say declared?)  once and every closure call will create a new struct instance S { v : i } of the single type S, or (2) struct S { ... } is defined every time a closure is called. The fact the code in the OP compiles implies the first interpretation is correct. That's just an empirical fact, so I want a documentation about it.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items.html

Items are entirely determined at compile-time, generally remain fixed during execution, and may reside in read-only memory.

(Items include structs).
Generally, rust does not define value-dependent types. Furthermore, items (including e.g. structs and functions) defined inside functions/closures cannot use values (e.g. variables) or even generic parameters from their parent, which strengthen the fact that being nested for items impact nothing other than visibility.

Also see Item declarations: "Declaring an item within a statement block restricts its scope ... It is otherwise identical in meaning to declaring the item inside a module ... There is no implicit capture"
